# How can I save an array character at the same index in another array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, replace

There must be an easy way to replace an element of an array in Ruby. I don't want to use regular expressions.

```
while @word_array.include? c do
  idx = @word_array.index(c)
  @currently_found[idx] = c
  @word_array.index(idx) = " "
end
```

I want to save the char *c* at the same index but in another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want it for (do you really want to change @word_array to contain a space?), but this should do it (except for additional nil's at end of array, don't know if that's a problem):

`@currently_found = @word_array.map { |w| w == c ? c : nil }`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the return value of [Array#index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-index). For example:

```
an_array     = %w[a b c]
new_array    = []
chars        = ['b']
chars.each do |char|
  new_array[an_array.index(char)] = char if an_array.include? char
end
new_array
=> [nil, "b"]
```